# Jquery, select and scroll next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a newbie jQuery question. I need to add a number of tiny text boxes with links to scroll up and down any overflowed content.

I've got it to work as follows, but need to rework it to handle repeated boxes of text on the page.

Javascript..

```
$(function() {
    $('a.scrolldown').click(function(event) {   
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".mytextbox").scrollTop($(".mytextbox").scrollTop() - 20);
    });
});
```

With the markup...

```
<div class="news_col">
    <p class="newscontrols">
     <a class="scrolldown" href="#">down </a><a class="scrollup" href="#">up</a></p>
     <div class="news_item_text mytextbox">
      <p>Loren ipsum...</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

I realise I could use maybe the 'next' selector but need a bit of help rewriting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) with `$(this)` to access the textbox after the `.scrolldown` anchor.

```
$(function() {
    $('a.scrolldown').click(function(event) {   
       event.preventDefault();
       $mytextbox = $(this).next(".mytextbox");
       $mytextbox.scrollTop($mytextbox.scrollTop() - 20);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Tweaked the markup with 'up' and 'down' `<a>` tags before and after the text container, using `next()` and `prev()`.